# Save while loop information after y/n response

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am having a problem with my code, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

I have made a calculator in C++ using Dev-C++. I made a `while` loop so the user doesn't have to restart the program to use it again. I am trying to add the ability for the previously calculated answer to be used in the next calculation, but the code is being skipped.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string username;
    float num1, num2, answer;
    string berekening;
    string again;
    float oldanswer;
    string oldanswerq;

    again = "y";

    cout << "Hello who are you?" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cin >> username;

    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "well hello " << username << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    while (again == "y"){

    oldanswer = answer;
        if (oldanswer == 0)    {
            cout << "what is the first number you wanna put in " << username << endl;
            cout << "" << endl;
            cin >> num1;
        }

        else {
            cout << "do you wanna use your old answer? y/n" << endl;
            cout << "" << endl;
            cin >> oldanswerq;
        }

        cout << "" << endl;
        cout << "+, -, x or ÷(u can use / instead of ÷" << endl;
        cout << "" << endl;
        cin >> berekening;

        cout << "" << endl;
        cout << "and what is the second number " << username << endl;
        cout << "" << endl;
        cin >> num2;

        cout << "" << endl;
        if (berekening == "+"){
            answer = num1 + num2;
        }

        else if (berekening == "-"){
            answer = num1 - num2;
        }

        else if (berekening == "x"){
            answer = num1 * num2;
        }

        else if (berekening == "/"){
            answer = num1 / num2;
        }

        else if (berekening == "÷"){
            answer = num1 / num2;
        }

        cout << username << ", you choosed " << berekening << " what i did was: " << num1 << berekening << num2 << "=" << answer << endl;
        cout << "" << endl;
        cout << username << ", do you wanna go again? y/n" << endl;
        cout << "" << endl;
        cin >> again;
        cout << "" << endl;
    }
}
```

I am new to C++ and would welcome suggested improvements.

Comment: Made you explanation a little bit more clear and fixed your code formatting and indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set `oldanswer` equal to `newanswer` outside the loop. It should be done inside the loop.

You should also not use `==` when comparing `float` as they are rarely exactly equal to something (decimals can only be accurate to a certain number of places on a computer).